# What parts of an Android app should be fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am going to develop an app with the following structure:

- Search: Lets user search for articles and displays search results in a list
- Article: Displays an article
- UserList: Displays a list of articles the user has chosen to add to the list
- UserListItem: An item that represents an article in the list mentioned above, and lets the user add custom information via some `EditText`-fields.

The *Search*, *Article* and *UserList* seem like they could be implemented as fragments. But what about the *UserListItem*? There will of course be multiple *UserListItems* on the screen at the same time, could it still be implemented as a fragment? If not, how should it be implemented?

I'm having some trouble grasping the whole fragment concept. It seems obvious how to use it in the standard scenario, i.e. *Search*-pane and *Article*-pane. But it's a bit unclear to me if it should/could be used in a scenario where you will have multiple instances of the same fragment displaying at the same time.

I haven't yet written any code, because I want to have the overall structure clear before I start, so I don't have to go back and change everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This might be a bit much if you are a beginner, but if you want to add searching capabilities in your application, consider [creating a search interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).
2. From the documentation on `Fragment`s:

   > You can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which
   >   has its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you
   >   can add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub
   >   activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

   That being said, there is a huge difference between incorporating a behavior in your screen's layout and wrapping that behavior in a `Fragment`. In your case, it really wouldn't make sense to wrap each list item in a `Fragment` as it would be ridiculously inefficient to instantiate a new `Fragment` for each item in your `ListView`. Representing each list item as a `Fragment` would give each row its own lifecycle, which is obviously not what you want. What you probably want to do instead is represent each list item in XML, and have the `Fragment` (or `Activity`) that holds your `ListView` manage these list items as necessary.